# UMD syntax with fallback global

Tags: build, module, typescript

### My Setup

I'm compiling my `.ts` module 'FooModule' into an [UMD module](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-umd-and-system-module-output) in Visual Studio 2015. I would like to extend this UMD syntax, so that the module will be injected into the global object as fallback when no module loading system is present, and I would like to automate this task as part of the build-process.

---

### The UMD Syntax

When compiling a TypeScript module with the UMD syntax (Universal Module Definition syntax), modules that are compatible with both RequireJS and NodeJS are emitted:

**foo-module.ts**

```
export class Foo {
    // ...
}
```

... is compiled into:

**foo-module.js**

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
        var v = factory(require, exports); if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var Foo = (function () {
        function Foo() {
        }
        return Foo;
    }());
    exports.Foo = Foo;
});
```

---

### Fallback to Global Inject

However, as part of the *Universal* part of UMD, I would like my module to be usable without any module loading system as well. ***My module has no dependencies.***

This is usually done by adding a third case as a fallback for when neither the RequireJS nor the NodeJS module system are present, which will effectively inject into the global object. For `foo-module`, this would look like:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
        var v = factory(require, exports); if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports"], factory);
    } else {
        // *****************************
        factory(null, global.FooModule || (global.FooModule = {})); // <- This part.
        // *****************************
    }
})(this, function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var Foo = (function () {
        function Foo() {
        }
        return Foo;
    }());

    // In browsers, this means 'window.FooModule.Foo = Foo'.
    exports.Foo = Foo;
});
```

I believe this would suffice in all cases when there are no external dependencies (assuming no two modules with the same name have been loaded this way).

I understand I can just rewrite manually after each build, but **how could I automate this task (or something with identical results) as part of a build-process in Visual Studio (2015)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand I can just rewrite manually after each build, but how could I automate this task (or something with identical results) as part of a build-process in Visual Studio (2015)?

You will have to create this yourself.

## More

There are a few variations of UMD : https://github.com/umdjs/umd the one you want is fallback *browser* global : https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/returnExports.js

This is not the version in TypeScript because *global* is pretty much *no module system*.

Comment: What I found to be a somewhat working solution is creating global fake require and define functions (when they do not already exist), which are effectively nothing more than wrappers for the fallback-global functionality.